# show nearby places based on saved longitude and latitude in database. angular6 + sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, angular6, distance

When the app is started, I want to show nearby (10 km) restaurants from my location, and those restaurants are saved in the database (SQL Server) as longitude and latitude.

Ex: Restaurant table

`restaurantId`, `name`, `longitude`, `latitude`

`1`, `Greek Restaurant`, `-72.374984`, `41.274672`

`2`, `Italian Restaurant`, `-73.483947`, `40.739283`

...

Let's say my location is

`longitude`: -74.009056

`latitude`: 40.713744

and if this can be solved using only sql, I would use stored procedure by passing these values as parameters, along with nearby value in km (10 km) (`@myLongitude`, `@myLatitude`, `@km`).

or if this can be solved using angular, I would call all data from restaurant table and do the calculation to sort them out.

These are my basic assumptions, but not sure if it is even feasible. 
How can I retrieve nearby restaurants (10 km) based on lng & lat saved in the database?

No map needed, I just want to bring it as a list. It would be even better to know how far each restaurant is (in km) from my location.

Thanks for your help, code snippets are so appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [Geography data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-2017) instead of latitude and longtitude. See following demo

```
--this is your table
CREATE TABLE Landmark (
    Id int,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Latitude FLOAT,
    Longitude FLOAT
)

INSERT Landmark VALUES
(1, 'Greek Restaurant', -72.374984, 41.274672),
(2, 'Italian Restaurant', -73.483947, 40.739283)

--this is better table to query
WITH GeographyLandmark AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(Longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326) Location
    FROM LandMark
)
--this query calculates distance between point and localizations in meters
SELECT Id, Name,
    geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(-74.009056 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(40.713744 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326).STDistance(Location) Distance
FROM GeographyLandmark
```

**Results:**

```
Id    Name                 Distance
----- -------------------- ----------------
1     Greek Restaurant     150944,610588657
2     Italian Restaurant   44456,82536079
```

References: [STDistance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017), [STPointFromText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stpointfromtext-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can this query take nearby value (10km)? And which one from  `Distance` ex: first row's  `15106428` or `9630214` should I use? Is the first one meaning how far it is away from my location in meters?

Comment: I switched latitude and longtitude - my mistake. Value 44456,82536079 means that Italian restaurant is 44456.825... meters (44.456852... km) from given point.

Comment: Thanks. I posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52239701/sql-server-geography-latitude-longitude-error) regarding an error please help.