# SQL Server geography latitude longitude error

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeography

I'm using geography data type for calculating shortest distance.

```
CREATE TABLE Landmark (
    Id int,   
    Latitude FLOAT,
    Longitude FLOAT
)

INSERT Landmark VALUES
(1, 49.242458, -123.153465),
(2, 49.249381, -122.866683)

WITH GeographyLandmark AS
(
    SELECT Id, geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(Latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(Longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326) Location
    FROM Landmark
)

--this query calculates distance between point and localizations in meters
SELECT Id, geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(49.2424566 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(-123.1534623 AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326).STDistance(Location) Distance
FROM GeographyLandmark
```

But I am getting this error:

> > A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
> >     System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.
> >     System.FormatException: 
> >        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeographyValidator.ValidatePoint(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
> >        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.Validator.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
> >        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.ForwardingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
> >        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.CoordinateReversingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
> >        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePointText(Boolean parseParentheses)
> >        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
> >        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
> >        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ParseText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
> >        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
> >     .

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've got the latitude and longitude switched. A couple of things:

1. An easy sanity check is to use the `Lat` and/or `Long` extended properties. Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/long-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) for `Long`.
2. Another extension that Microsoft's implementation provides is the `Point` static method for creating points. So instead of having to create the WKT for a point to pass to `STPointFromText`, you can just do `geography::Point(Latitude, Longitude, SRID)`. Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) for that.